# Dagger class could not be bound with key

Tags: android, mvp, dagger

I am trying to provide SettingsPresenter to SettingsActivity (View) and got "dagger class could not be bound with key" error, please help me fix it and figure out reason of the error.

error:

```
Error:(32, 8) error: presenter.ISettingsPresenter could not be bound with key presenter.ISettingsPresenter required by ui.activity.settings.SettingsActivity for dagger.AppModule
```

ModelsModule provides securityModel and userModel and it's working fine;

My code is:

**SettingsActivity:**

```java
SettingsActivity implements ISettingsView {
   @Inject ISettingsPresenter presenter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //...
       createScopedGraph(new SettingsModule(this)).inject(this);
       presenter.onCreate();
       //...
   }

   public ObjectGraph createScopedGraph(Object... modules) {
       return objectGraph.plus(modules);
   }
}
```

**AppModule:**

```java
@Module(
    injects = {
            App.class,
    },
    includes = {
            AnalyticsModule.class,
            ModelsModule.class
    })

public class AppModule {
private App app;
public AppModule(App app) {
    this.app = app;
}
```

**SettingsModule:**

```java
@Module(
    injects = SettingsActivity.class,
    addsTo = AppModule.class,
    complete = false)

public class SettingsModule {

    private final ISettingsView view;

    public SettingsModule(ISettingsView settingsView) {
        this.view = settingsView;
    }

    @Provides
    public ISettingsView provideView() {
        return this.view;
    }

    @Provides
    public ISettingsPresenter providePresenter(ISettingsView view, UserModel userModel, SecurityModel securityModel) {
        return new SettingsPresenter(view, userModel, securityModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to figure out the issue ?